# Return all records with Eloquent query filters

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm building a form which allows the user to select from several options and retrieve results from the DB based on these. I've been successful in creating my query filters, but am running into issues when I want to add the option 'select records from all time' instead of by a specific year.

My code is as follows:

```
$order = (new Order)->newQuery();

    if ($request->has('report')) {
        if($request->report === 'all') {
            $order->where('status', 'approved')
            ->orWhere('status', 'pending')
            ->orWhere('status', 'denied');
        } else {
            $order->where('status', $request->report);
        } 
    }

    if($request->has('supervisors')) {
        $order->where(function($query) use ($request) {
            foreach ($request->supervisors as $key => $supervisor) {
                if ($key == 0)  {
                    $query->where('supervisor_id', $supervisor);
                } else {
                    $query->orWhere('supervisor_id', $supervisor);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    if($request->dateFrom !== null) {
        $order->whereBetween('created_at', 
            [
                Carbon::parse($request->dateFrom), 
                Carbon::parse($request->dateTo)
            ]);
    } elseif($request->has('year') !== null) {
        $order->whereYear('created_at', $request->year);
    } 
    if(isset($request->allTime)) {
        $order;
    }
    return $order->get();
```

The problematic part is here:

```
if(isset($request->allTime)) {
    $order;
}
```

My understanding is that if no filtering has taken place with dateFrom or Year then it should just return all items by default, but this isn't happening. I just receive a blank result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont need to add any filtering for all time then you can just omit it or leave the if block blank

```
if(isset($request->allTime)) { }
```

You should also fix `$request->has('year') !== null` because it looks like 2 conditions in one 
$request->has('year') always returns true or false depending on whether year exists in Request. true or false will never be == null

```
$request->has('year') && $request->year !== null
```

Comment: Hey, that's what I thought but it's just returning a null result if I do that. If I explicitly add all the years as a range then it return the result but by default it's not returning any result.

Comment: how about if you fix `$request->has('year') !== null`

Comment: Depending on your Laravel version.. `has` is not the same as `filled`. `?var=` would produce a true for `$request->has("var")` but `$request->filled("var")` would be false.

Comment: Hey Blake. thanks for that. I didn't know. Will use for future code :)